# .Htaccess redirect giving 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Today I'm attempting to redirect

```
Http://www.motorcyclemonster.com/MyMRa/
```

to

```
Http://www.mymra.com/
```

The problem is I can't add anything without getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I can't even add a regular redirect without getting the dreadful 500 internal server error.

Supposedly there's a error file, however I can't find it.

Anyone have any idea why this problem might occur?

Htaccess file:

http://pastebin.com/7EQxZFCx

Sent to pastebin for simplicity reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure what type of server you're running, but if you're on Linux/Unix check /var/log/

Comment: @Louis - I'm on Linux however I'm without a var/log/ directory.

Comment: Look at the server error log. That'll have more details about the 500. but invariably you've got a syntax error, and it's far easier to turn on logging and read the log than it is to try and figure out what's going on in your .htaccess.

Comment: Your .htaccess could probably be shrunk a great deal by using RedirectMatch.  You have variants for different URLs that go to the same place, like `/Events/Events.html` and `/events/events.html`.  RedirectMatch will let you use a regular expression to handle both of those without having to spell out all the variations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andy! I've just been thrown into this project so I'm trying to clean it up and make it more friendly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is too big for me to sift through. Perhaps you could do a binary search, deleting parts of the file until it works. Then, as soon as you've narrowed it down, paste that portion.

Comment: Everything below line 37 is irrelevant. Those are regular redirects which work fine. The problem is whenever I add a NEW redirect.

Comment: Line 19 %{THE_REQUEST} isn't valid.

Comment: When removing line 19 I come across with an error stating the link http://www.motorcyclemonster.com is redirecting in a way that will never complete. Any ideas?

Comment: On line 21, the code basically says "redirect everything to itself". There's your loop.

Comment: That last suggestion did it!